# Recovery? Accidentally formated whole disk when installing Xubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, data-recovery, format, testdisk

today I attempted to install Xubuntu on my machine.
I had Ubuntu and Windows on my SSD as dual boot. 
I wanted to expand the volume that the Ubuntu had because it was way too small. What I did, mistakenly, though is to format the whole disk so I lost my Windows partition (of course).

I tried to recover at least partially my Win partition with TestDisk via Live Ubuntu flash drive.

I can see the drive, when I try to search for volumes, however when I get in there in order to recover the files, it tells me:

> Can't open filesystem. Filesystem seems damaged.

Is there a way that I can recover, at least partially, some of the files on my Win partition, now called *Unallocated space*?

[image: Drive listed as MS data (screenshot)]

[image: Can't open filesystem (screenshot)]

P.S. [How do I recover my accidentally lost Windows partitions after installing Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu)

This question not related ENTIRELY to my problem. The thing is that all of the ways to recover my partition suggested there are not seeing the partition I've mentioned. On the other hand, with TestDisk tool I can see it.

Comment: There are a couple data recovery tools out there. https://www.lifewire.com/free-data-recovery-software-tools-2622893 https://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/other-recovery-software/bootable-hard-drive-recovery.htm (I haven't tried any of these, and you should probably do some research first)

Comment: @Riggah If none of the several methods [described in the answers there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu) help you (some of them use testdisk, some do not), or you have strong reason to think they will not or that they are otherwise not appropriate to your problem, then please **[edit]** this question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to recover the other partitions marked as D (deleted) but starting at the same point ? Typically the one from 718851 to 233517055 (use gparted to see if it matches the size of *Unallocated space*). Then try to list the files with P.
Last resort is to try a deeper search, which is going to take quite a long time.
The message concerning the damaged filesystem may be provoked by a sector being partially written over after the formatting, in which case there is little hope.

Comment: Good thought. I have actually researched on that, and what I found was that the Gparted shows the **unallocated space** as 60 gb, when my win partition was 82 gb. (the problem comes with me giving to Xubuntu 20 additional GBs from (apparently) the windows partition)
Regarding saving other D partitions, its telling me that it can't load any backup for them, so it can't proceed.